# Create JSON using PHP with data which contains JSON

Tags: php, json

How can I create JSON using PHP with data which contains JSON without including a bunch of escape characters in the JSON, and without converting JSON first to an array or object, and then back to JSON?

```
<?php
/*
GIVEN: Data from DB contained in array $a.
I know that sometimes JSON shouldn't be stored in a DB, but please assume this is a good case for doing so.
*/
$a[0]=json_encode(['a'=>5,'b'=>'hello']);
$a[1]=json_encode(['a'=>2,'b'=>'how are you']);
$a[2]=json_encode(['a'=>7,'b'=>'goodby']);

$o=[
    ['x'=>321,'y'=>$a[0]],
    ['x'=>123,'y'=>$a[1]],
    ['x'=>111,'y'=>$a[2]],
];

echo('<pre>'.print_r($o,1).'</pre>');
echo(json_encode($o));
/*
Undesired result containing a bunch of escape characters.  Granted, they are benign, however, will increase network trafic.
[{"x":321,"y":"{\"a\":5,\"b\":\"hello\"}"},{"x":123,"y":"{\"a\":2,\"b\":\"how are you\"}"},{"x":111,"y":"{\"a\":7,\"b\":\"goodby\"}"}]
*/

$o=[
    ['x'=>321,'y'=>json_decode($a[0])],
    ['x'=>123,'y'=>json_decode($a[1])],
    ['x'=>111,'y'=>json_decode($a[2])],
];

echo('<pre>'.print_r($o,1).'</pre>');
echo(json_encode($o));
/*
Desired result, however, is there a more efficient way to do this?
[{"x":321,"y":{"a":5,"b":"hello"}},{"x":123,"y":{"a":2,"b":"how are you"}},{"x":111,"y":{"a":7,"b":"goodby"}}]
*/
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with storing JSON Strings in a database. MYSQL5.7 even adds extensions to process JSON within a query

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I agree, however, often people will criticize doing so stating that "databases should store data the way they were meant to".  Also, I am using SQLite and not MySQL for this application, and don't need to process it.

Comment: I would aim for having native data structure first (second option). It's response representation may vary (json, xml, html, pdf), so it will be processed by some abstract entity at some point. You'll get into troubles with polymorphism, unless you have well defined data (parameter) structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no faster way then to decode, mutate and encode again.

You could however combine the decoding code closely with your database queries. If you have a data model class, you would do the decoding there, so that the code that calls this service will never see the JSON, but always the decoded data.

Then, again, in the data model, where you write to the database, you would perform the JSON encoding at the last moment.

This way you hide the JSON factor behind the walls of the data layer, and the rest of the application will not have to be aware of that.

#### Manipulating JSON directly

Another solution consists of writing a library that can juggle with JSON, giving possibilities to set values inside JSON without the caller having to decode/encode. This option requires much more code (or you could find an existing library), and so it is not really my first recommendation. But here is a naive example of a function that could exist in that library:

```
function json_set($json, $path, $value) {
    $arr = json_decode($json, true);
    $ref =& $arr;
    $props = explode("/", $path);
    $finalProp = array_pop($props);
    foreach ($props as $key) {
        if (!isset($ref[$key])) $ref[$key] = [];
        $ref =& $ref[$key];
    }
    $obj = json_decode($value);
    $ref[$finalProp] = $obj ? $obj : $value;
    return json_encode($arr);
}
```

This allows you to provide an existing JSON string, a path pointing to a certain spot inside that JSON, and a value that should be put there. That value could itself also be JSON.

Here is how you would use it in your case, given the JSON values in *$a* which you got from the database:

```
$o=json_encode([
    ['x'=>321],
    ['x'=>123],
    ['x'=>111],
]);

$o = json_set($o, '0/y', $a[0]);
$o = json_set($o, '1/y', $a[1]);
$o = json_set($o, '2/y', $a[2]);

echo $o;
```

Output:

```
[{"x":321,"y":{"a":5,"b":"hello"}},
 {"x":123,"y":{"a":2,"b":"how are you"}},
 {"x":111,"y":{"a":7,"b":"goodby"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks trincot.  So, options such as JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES the second depth argument are not possibilities?  I messed with them, and I was surprised to find that they don't seem to help.  I don't need to do much juggling and am also considering just manually writing the JSON, but doing so makes me a little nervous.

Comment: The `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` only influences how forward slashes are encoded, but nothing else. If you encode something that already has JSON (as a quoted string value ), then it is only expected that the double quotes inside that string are escaped (with backslashes -- something different than forward slashes). Personally, I would advise against manually writing JSON, even for the smallest objects.